# Removing duplicate parameters from post or URL

Tags: security

I have a security concern raised by a security consultant with regards to a website of one of my clients:

Using **Burp Suite Community Edition**, running a POST request with the following parameter string:

`search=Search&city=Johannesburg&city=Madrid`

PHP populates the POST array to this:

```
Array
(
    [search] => Search
    [city] => Madrid
)
```

This is obvious that it would happen, but I want to know if my attempt to resolve this potential problem has any downsides, except the things I can think of, which I will mention below. Here is my attempted code (PHP, CodeIgniter 3):

```
$raw_input = explode('&', $this->input->raw_input_stream);
if (!empty($raw_input)) {
    $new_post = [];
    foreach ($raw_input as $key => $value) {
        $param = explode('=', $value);
        if (!isset($new_post[$param[0]])) {
            $new_post[$param[0]] = $param[1];
        }
    }
    if (!empty($new_post)) {
        $_POST = $new_post;
    }
}
```

This results in my output to be as follows, which is at face value what I want to achieve:

```
Array
(
    [search] => Search
    [city] => Johannesburg
)
```

Now - I can see a few points of concern:

- I am aware that I still have to do XSS clean and all those nice security things on the POST. **[I just do that elsewhere as needed - this part of code I wish to run at the earliest part possible to ensure that it runs for every page/request]**
- I will have to do this for GET and probably all other HTTP verbs as well. **[Which ones? All of them?]**
- What if the hacker manages to inject the duplicate parameter before the valid one? **[Is that possible?]**
- Why am I reinventing the wheel for something that probably already exists? **[Because I do not know where to find a proper solution, or what it would even look like.]**

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fail to see how this duplicate parameter matter is related to any concern expressed here.

Comment: I even fail to see any problem at all.

Comment: The consultant said that this request is possibly vulnerable to blind SQL injection. I do not know exactly how it could be exploited, but I am not an expert on this, hence I am asking for assistance.

Comment: Well, at the very least, I can see inaccurate data, and although this simplistic example probably has no impact, a real life example could result in a user receiving a package intended for another user by changing the address details.

Comment: This request obviously has absolutely nothing to do with SQL injections as no SQL is involved here at all. I suspect either a misunderstanding or this "consultant" being an impostor.

Comment: When a user has to receive a package, obviously you have to check whether a package belongs to them. Regardless of any duplicate parameter concern

Comment: Well, if the data enters the system via unintended means, you won't always know that the address was hacked. How would you really know? As for SQL injection, well, I am passing a parameter and if I don't sanitize, it could have SQL injection, but I am sanitizing, so maybe you're right that it can't be exploited that way, but I have to do my due diligence with regards to my client's system, and do what needs to be done. It is as simple as that for me. If the problem is a non-issue, then great :-)

Comment: What do you mean, "hacked"? To "hack" an input parameter you just write whatever you wish. That's input. It can be anything by definition.

Comment: Here I "hacked" the input parameter of this very question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70800836/wtf-this-question-is-about`

Comment: What I mean with hack is to actually change a value with intent to do harm. If you look at the answer given so far (and the article it links to), you can see that there seem to be ways where this can be exploited. You could display wrong articles on a site, you can, with other vulnerabilities, do injections, etc. If the general consensus is that you need to do manual testing for this (as also indicated in the article), I have a big task ahead of me, as it is a huge system, providing the client can justify the cost of a potentially very low impact issue. But that is not my decision.

Comment: You could display wrong articles on a site, you can, with other vulnerabilities, do injections, etc. **without any "parameter pollution" at all**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have described goes by the name [parameter pollution](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/07-Input_Validation_Testing/04-Testing_for_HTTP_Parameter_Pollution). It is a bit bug, a bit feature of the web servers. It may have security implications if - for example - your filter layer checks access rights on the first occurrence of the `userid` attribute, but the business logic takes the last occurrence of the attribute. You will get an inconsistency that may be exploited.

If you are vulnerable to such type of attack - for me it is a strong evidence that you are doing something wrong inside the code, like you take the message body and extract the attributes manually from the POST requests and you do it different way in two different parts of your code.

If you don't do anything really stupid, this kind of attacks will not hurt the system and does not need any kind of mitigation code.

Unless you really must fix stuff like this, in which case I would say - take a WAF to clear the request before it even reaches the web server.

Comment: Hi Marek. Thank you for your answer. It does make some sense, and I can see how it can be exploited now. Tell me, though, if I do $this->input->post('user_id'), PHP would've used the second one as the actual post variable for "user_id" which means that the exploit could happen, even if I don't do anything stupid. Remember, I am not talking about a regular user of the system, but a bad actor, who intends to cause harm here. So, under normal use, I would not have to do anything about this, but what about exceptional cases, such as a hacking attempt?

Comment: From the article you linked: "As a general rule: if existing input validation and other security mechanisms are sufficient on single inputs, and if the server assigns only the first or last polluted parameters, then parameter pollution does not reveal a vulnerability." - that confirms that I do not have to do anything in "normal use" but there is seemingly no way to globally fix this application wide.

Comment: Based on your answer, do you believe the piece of code I attempt to fix the issue with has merits? Should I keep it? Discard it? Try something totally different? Do nothing?

Comment: There was a time where I played with parameter pollution myself to gain confidence in my application. It turned out I could not disrupt a single thing. Feel free to play with your application too. I would not implement any prevention unless I would have proven that a vulnerability really exists.